# Python Selenium run multiple tests in one browser instance?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

How can I run multiple tests from different modules in one browser instance in Selenium? For example, if I have a test to login, and another tests to do an action *after* logging in, can I string these tests together? So that the webdriver logs in first, then conducts the second test? I'm using Python 2.7.5 to write the tests.

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1):

This depends on capabilities of your test runner. [Nose test framefowrk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.3.0) allows you to define [package level setup methods](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-packages) as well as module, class, and method setups.

Another method for manually providing the browser instance from another class is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627176/selenium-webdriver-in-python-re-using-same-web-browser-across-testcases?rq=1#answer-10627326) to similar question.